# HID submit HID_XFER_PACKET to simulate keystrokes

Tags: windows, driver, hid, kmdf

I'm trying to write a KMDF driver to simulate keystrokes.

When the driver receives `IOCTL_HID_READ_REPORT` it redirects the request to a queue:

```
switch (IoControlCode)
{
case IOCTL_HID_GET_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR:
    KdPrint(("GET DEVICE DESCRIPTOR\n"));
    _Analysis_assume_(deviceContext->HidDescriptor.bLength != 0);
    status = RequestCopyFromBuffer(Request, &deviceContext->HidDescriptor, deviceContext->HidDescriptor.bLength);
    break;

case IOCTL_HID_GET_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTES:
    KdPrint(("GET DEVICE ATTRIBUTES\n"));
    status = RequestCopyFromBuffer(Request, &queueContext->DeviceContext->HidDeviceAttributes, sizeof(HID_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTES));
    break;

case IOCTL_HID_GET_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR:
    KdPrint(("GET REPORT DESCRIPTOR\n"));
    status = RequestCopyFromBuffer(Request, deviceContext->ReportDescriptor, deviceContext->HidDescriptor.DescriptorList[0].wReportLength);
    break;

case IOCTL_HID_READ_REPORT:
   WdfRequestForwardToIoQueue(Request, QueueContext->DeviceContext->ManualQueue); // <= HERE
    break;}
```

With a timer, items are regularly dequeued and the keyboard input report is copied in the request

```
void EvtTimerFunc(_In_  WDFTIMER Timer)
{
    NTSTATUS                status;
    WDFQUEUE                queue;
    PMANUAL_QUEUE_CONTEXT   queueContext;
    WDFREQUEST              request;


    KdPrint(("EvtTimerFunc\n"));

    queue = (WDFQUEUE)WdfTimerGetParentObject(Timer);
    queueContext = GetManualQueueContext(queue);

    //
    // see if we have a request in manual queue
    //
    status = WdfIoQueueRetrieveNextRequest(queueContext->Queue, &request);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        KdPrint(("Handling"));

        HID_XFER_PACKET hidXferPacket;

        BYTE keycodes[6] = {0};
        keycodes[0] = 0x04;

        HID_KEYBOARD_INPUT_REPORT report;
        report.ReportId = REPORT_ID_KEYBOARD_INPUT;
        report.Modifiers = 0;
        report._reserved = 0;
        memcpy(&report.KeyCodes, &keycodes, 6);

        hidXferPacket.reportBuffer = (UCHAR*)&report;
        hidXferPacket.reportBufferLen = sizeof(HID_KEYBOARD_INPUT_REPORT);
        hidXferPacket.reportId = REPORT_ID_KEYBOARD_INPUT;

        RequestCopyFromBuffer(request, hidXferPacket.reportBuffer, sizeof(HID_KEYBOARD_INPUT_REPORT));
        
        WdfRequestComplete(request, status);
    }
}
```

Although everything works without error, no keystroke are emitted. What am I missing ?!

Descriptor:

```
HID_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR g_reportDescriptor[] = {
    0x05, 0x01,        // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x02,        // USAGE (Mouse)
    0xA1, 0x01,        // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x85,                  REPORT_ID_MOUSE_INPUT,
    0x09, 0x01,            // USAGE_PAGE (Pointer)
    0xA1, 0x00,            // COLLECTION (Physical)
    0x05, 0x09,                // USAGE_PAGE (Buttons)
    0x19, 0x01,                // USAGE_MINIMUM (1)
    0x29, 0x03,                // USAGE_MAXIMUM (3)
    0x15, 0x00,                // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,                // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x95, 0x03,                // REPORT_COUNT (3)
    0x75, 0x01,                // REPORT_SIZE (1)
    0x81, 0x02,                // INPUT (Data, Variable, Absolute)
    0x95, 0x01,                // REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x75, 0x05,                // REPORT_SIZE (5)
    0x81, 0x01,                // INPUT (Constant)
    0x05, 0x01,                // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x30,                // USAGE (X)
    0x09, 0x31,                // USAGE (Y)
    0x15, 0x81,                // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
    0x25, 0x7F,                // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
    0x75, 0x08,                // REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x95, 0x02,                // REPORT_COUNT (2)
    0x81, 0x06,                // Input (Data, Variable, Relative)
    0xC0,                  // END_COLLECTION
    0xC0,              // END_COLLECTION

    0x05, 0x01,        // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x00,        // USAGE (Undefined)
    0xa1, 0x01,        // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x85,                  REPORT_ID_MOUSE_OUTPUT,
    0x09, 0x00,            // USAGE (Undefined)
    0x15, 0x00,            // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x26, 0xff, 0x00,      // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (255)
    0x95, 0x03,            // REPORT_COUNT (3)
    0x75, 0x08,            // REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x91, 0x02,            // OUTPUT (Data, Variable, Absolute)
    0xc0,              // END_COLLECTION

    0x05, 0x01,        // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x06,        // USAGE (Keyboard)
    0xA1, 0x01,        // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x85,                  REPORT_ID_KEYBOARD_INPUT,
    0x05, 0x07,            // USAGE_PAGE (Keyboard Key Codes)
    0x19, 0xE0,            // USAGE_MINIMUM (224)
    0x29, 0xE7,            // USAGE_MAXIMUM (231)
    0x15, 0x00,            // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x01,            // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
    0x75, 0x01,            // REPORT_SIZE (1)
    0x95, 0x08,            // REPORT_COUNT (8)
    0x81, 0x02,            // INPUT (Data, Variable, Absolute)
    0x95, 0x01,            // REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x75, 0x08,            // REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x81, 0x01,            // INPUT (Constant)
    0x19, 0x00,            // USAGE_MINIMUM (0)
    0x29, 0x65,            // USAGE_MAXIMUM (101)
    0x15, 0x00,            // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x25, 0x65,            // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (101)
    0x95, 0x06,            // REPORT_COUNT (6)
    0x75, 0x08,            // REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x81, 0x00,            // INPUT (Data, Array, Absolute)
    0x05, 0x08,            // USAGE_PAGE (LEDs)
    0x19, 0x01,            // USAGE_MINIMUM (Num Lock)
    0x29, 0x05,            // USAGE_MAXIMUM (Kana)
    0x95, 0x05,            // REPORT_COUNT (5)
    0x75, 0x01,            // REPORT_SIZE (1)
    0x91, 0x02,            // OUTPUT (Data, Variable, Absolute)
    0x95, 0x01,            // REPORT_COUNT (1)
    0x75, 0x03,            // REPORT_SIZE (3)
    0x91, 0x01,            // OUTPUT (Constant)
    0xC0,              // END_COLLECTION

    0x05, 0x01,        // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x00,        // USAGE (Undefined)
    0xa1, 0x01,        // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x85,                  REPORT_ID_KEYBOARD_OUTPUT,
    0x09, 0x00,            // USAGE (Undefined)
    0x15, 0x00,            // LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x26, 0xff, 0x00,      // LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (255)
    0x95, 0x08,            // REPORT_COUNT (8)
    0x75, 0x08,            // REPORT_SIZE (8)
    0x91, 0x02,            // OUTPUT (Data, Variable, Absolute)
    0xc0               // END_COLLECTION
};

HID_DESCRIPTOR g_hidDescriptor = {
    0x09,        // length of HID descriptor
    0x21,        // descriptor type == HID 0x21
    0x0100,      // hid spec release
    0x00,        // country code == Not Specified
    0x01,        // number of HID class descriptors
    {            // DescriptorList[0]
        0x22,                             // report descriptor type 0x22
        sizeof(g_reportDescriptor)        // total length of report descriptor
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a Hyper V virtual machine as a debug machine, and this is why it didn't work.
As soon as I used another computer, the keystrokes were sent.

If you're trying to emulate keystroke or mouse move, this is what I recommend:

- Have a look at https://github.com/djpnewton/vmulti (integrate HidMapper to your driver)
- Avoid using Hyper V for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

How did you connect to your Hyper V debug machine?

In my case it happens on Hyper V virtual machine too, and it was OK on the physical machine or VMware virtual machine, but... I realized, that it happens only when I connect to it via RDP, and it's working as expected on Hyper V virtual machine when I connected to it through console.
So, I just leave there my notes about my situations:

As I understand, mouse/keyboard RDP drivers work on RDP session and can generate events, but only they can. So, the case can be resolved with several options:

1. use UMFD/KMFD lowerfilters driver (for example, it can be based on [HID Minidriver Sample (UMDF version 2)](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/hid/vhidmini2) only when you disconnected from RDP session (and rdp drivers disappear) with `sleep 5 | tscon.exe 2 /dest:console` command, executed as administrator from powershell console (to make available GUI without RDP and has control on it via driver)
2. use another kernel upperfilters driver "to control" RPD drivers only if that drivers are available (only while you stay logged in rdp session), moreover you have to use exactly device_id == rdp_device_id to inject strokes via sendinput interfaces:

   - Classic [Interception signed driver](https://github.com/dimonstrik/Interception) with [Interceptor wrapper](https://github.com/dimonstrik/Interceptor)
   - Good constructed native/managed [InputEmulator driver](https://github.com/dimonstrik/InputEmulator)
   - maybe [MS HIDInjector based on vfh driver](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-IoT-Samples/tree/master/samples/HIDInjector)
   - maybe [MS filters based driver](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/main/input)

P/s also similar case was described and answered by me in [ms question](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/714447/usb-hid-on-rdp-(remote-desktop))